# Wordpress posts display in Zigzag format using bootstrap

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to display posts in the following attached format. But, Posts are displaying one after one..

**Expected output :**

[image]

And Here is my code

```
<?php
  $type = 'post';
  $args=array('category__in'=> array(4), 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'order'=>'DESC');
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $i=1;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6" <?php if($i%2==1){?> style="float:left;" <?php }?> style="text-align: center;">
        <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="title_content">
        <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
$i++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

### Current Output screenshot

[image]

Comment: share screenshot of current output.

Comment: There should only be one style attribute at each tag

Comment: @VasimVanzara, Attached my current output screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For re-ordering columns in bootstrap you can use **pull/push** concept (till bootstrap 4). Or **order-** concept(from bootstrap 4). As you are using bootstrap 4. try below code:

```
<?php
  $type = 'post';
  $args=array('category__in'=> array(4), 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'order'=>'DESC');
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $i=1;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 <?php if($i%2==1){ echo 'order-sm-2';} ?>">
        <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="title_content">
        <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
$i++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Glad to help @kumar. :)

Answer (score 1):

Get a Zigzag layout you have execute code alternativly.

```
<?php
  $type = 'post';
  $args=array('category__in'=> array(4), 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'order'=>'DESC');
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $i=1;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="row">
        <?php if($i%2==1){?>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="title_content">
        <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      </div>
        </div>
      <?php } else {?>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <div class="title_content">
            <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
            <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
          </div>
           <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
            <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </figure>
          </div>
            </div>
      <?php } ?>

  </div>
<?php
$i++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Same out out  :(

Comment: Is variable $i=1 or $i=0 before while loop..?

Comment: @kumar try Jasbir's answer. It will help you

Comment: Jasbir's code worked awesome, But it shows different in mobile view.
The format should come one after one like Image, Title and Content

Comment: Design purspactive same here. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $type = 'post';
  $args=array('category__in'=> array(4), 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'order'=>'DESC');
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  $i=1;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
  if($i%2==0) {
  ?>
  <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
       <div class="title_content">
        <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">

       <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </figure>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } else { ?>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <div class="title_content">
        <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <?php } 
$i++;
endwhile;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: @kumar if this solution works for you please mark this answer as a solution

Comment: Your code works for me in desktop. But, when we go in mobile view, the format should come (Image, Title, Content) And (Image Title Content) And (Image Title Content). Your code displaying in mobile (Image Title Content) And (Title Content Image) and (Image title Content)

Comment: http://forealapp.com/new/  I have used your code.. Please check this in mobile, Hope you can understand then...

Comment: @kumar try my answer below, Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

With pure CSS, you could just apply `float: left` and `float: right` alternatingly to the `figure`element, using `row:nth-child(odd)` and `row:nth-child(even)` for the parent row to adress them accordingly.

Since you'll be using the `.row` class also at other positions on the page, you should apply a dedicated class to those rows which serve as containers for the posts. So if `.post-container` would be the additional class for these rows, the CSS would be

```
.post-container:nth-child(odd) .pro-innerpage-img {
  float: left;
}
.post-container:nth-child(even) .pro-innerpage-img {
  float: right;
}
```

Note: In this case the `figure` element should be in the same container as the content.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to style the contents:

```
.row:nth-child(odd) div figure { float: left;}
.row:nth-child(odd) div div { float: right;}
.row:nth-child(even) div figure { float: right;}
.row:nth-child(even) div div { float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<?php
  $type = 'post';
  $args=array('category__in'=> array(4), 'post_type' => $type, 'posts_per_page'=>3, 'order'=>'DESC');
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args); $i=1; ?>
     <div class="row">
        <?php while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php if($i%2==1){ $class = 'odd'; } else { $class = 'even'; } ?>
                <div class="col-sm-6 img <?php echo $class; ?>" style="text-align: center;">
                    <figure class="pro-innerpage-img">
                        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                    </figure>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 desc <?php echo $class; ?>" >
                    <div class="title_content">
                        <h4><?php the_title();?></h4>
                        <div><?php the_content(); ?></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <?php $i++; endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
  </div>
```

in CSS,

```
.desc.odd {
    float: left;
}
.img.odd {
    float: right;
}
```